# Flutter autocomplete stops working after launching Android emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I ran into a problem where Android Studio/IntelliJ Flutter/Dart autocomplete and imports suggestion stops working. Once AS is restarted the problem disappears.

Description and steps to reproduces are given below.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Open existing Flutter project in Android Studio;
2. Create a new variable;
3. Click Alt+Enter to import the variable's class;
4. The Dart package is imported;
5. Launch Android emulator
6. Create another variable;
7. Click Alt+Enter to import the variable's class;
   *Expected*: class is imported
   *Actual*: No import suggestions are given. When writing the class name, no autocomplete

**Software versions**
Windows 10 Pro x64
Android Studio 4.1.2
Android Emulator 30.3.5 version

**Flutter doctor**
Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.685], locale lt-LT)

**System**
Dell Precision 7540

I tried googling for this but haven't found similar questions. I guess this is related to what ports are used by the Dart analysis server and the Android emulator. Restarting AS 20 times per day doesn't seem like an efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the vscode-dart developers he has created a fix for this which *should* be in the next major release: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44650

Sidenote that i've been struggling with this issue for ages as well so I'm hoping it really will be fixed